# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in testng

Tags: java, testng

I am getting the above error in my program while testing testNG. I also installed my testng plugin through help->install new.

I am aware that *NoClassDefFoundError* means that the class is present in the classpath at Compile time, but it doesn't exist in the classpath at Runtime.

Below is my stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Stage
    at org.testng.internal.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:33)
    at org.testng.TestNG.init(TestNG.java:216)
    at org.testng.TestNG.<init>(TestNG.java:200)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.<init>(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:17)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.<init>(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:18)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNGFactory6_12.createRemoteTestNG(RemoteTestNGFactory6_12.java:16)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:67)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Stage
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 7 more
```

Im not sure on how to change my classpath file to solve the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

My java class file is also in the src folder which looks like this.

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class ScreencastTestClass {

    @BeforeTest
    public void StartRCServiver() {
        System.out.println(" RC server starting......");
    }

    public void testLogIn() {
        System.out.println(" Test is executing......");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void ShutDownRCServer() {
        System.out.println(" RC server stopping......");
    }

}
```

There is no pom file and the below are the existing files and folder structure.
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: In Eclipse, configuration is done via the IDE menus. See item ___Run Configurations...___ in menu _Run_ Here you configure the runtime classpath (as opposed to the build classpath). Of-course if you are using a java version greater than 8, you may need to configure the module path rather than the classpath.

Comment: @AnishB. it is added

Comment: Also add the pom.xml.

Comment: @AnishB. check my updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the missing `google-guice-core` dependency in the `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or download the jar from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/4.1.0/) and add it to the classpath.

Comment: Not yet. In Run Configuration->classpath the Add buttons are disabled

Comment: @ShaviPathirana No !! Right Click on the project -> Open properties -> Open Java Build Path -> Click on Libraries -> Click on Add External jars or Add jar (based on where you kept the jar file) and not from `Run Configurations`.